# D3: Bars not resizing upon window resize, for bar-chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have tried multiple ways of doing this, none work. Some break my chart, most simply don't work.
2 principal ways tried:

- Using 'viewBox': I must be using it wrong
- Using `d3.select(window).on('resize' function() { // resize })`: Simply doesn't work

Am I just doing something totally wrong or outdated in the way I have created this? Just learning some basics of D3 now.

Using d3 v7, fairly straightforward code:
jsFiddle of same: https://jsfiddle.net/5n7Lm80b/

Please note that commented out code is mostly stuff I have tried.

```js
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3@7.4.4";

const dataset = [
{
timestamp: "2022-05-16T21:15:00+00:00",
value: 1,
},
{
timestamp: "2022-05-16T21:18:00+00:00",
value: 2,
},
{
timestamp: "2022-05-16T21:21:00+00:00",
value: 1,
},
{
timestamp: "2022-05-16T21:30:00+00:00",
value: 1,
}
];

const svgWidth = document.body.offsetWidth, // document.querySelector('.class').offsetWidth;
      svgHeight = 300,
      barPadding = 5,
      barWidth = (svgWidth / dataset.length);

// Define container
const svg = d3.select('svg')
  // .attr('viewbox', [0,0,800,svgHeight])
  // .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYmin meet');
  // .attr('width', svgWidth) // allows content/bars to take up 
  // .attr('width', document.querySelector('.viewport').offsetWidth) // allows content/bars to take up entire width of container
  .attr('height', svgHeight);

// y scale
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(
    dataset,
    function(d) { 
      return d.value;
    }
  )])
  .range([0, svgHeight]);

// Define actual chart
const barChart = svg.selectAll('rect')
  // .append('svg')
  // .attr('viewBox', '0,0,400,400')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  // .attr('viewBox', '0,0,1000,400')
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return svgHeight - yScale(d.value);
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .attr('width', (document.querySelector('.viewport').offsetWidth / dataset.length) - barPadding)
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    const translate = [barWidth * i, 0];
    return `translate(${translate})`;
  })
  .attr('stroke', 'blue')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
  console.log('resize', document.querySelector('.viewport').offsetWidth);
  
  svg.selectAll('rect').attr('width', (document.querySelector('.viewport').offsetWidth / dataset.length) - barPadding);
})


// y axis
const yAxisScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(
    dataset,
    function(d) { 
      return d.value;
    }
  )])
  .range([svgHeight, 0]); // goes backwards=>bottom to top (negative)

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yAxisScale);

svg.append('g')
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(20, 10)')
  .attr('color', 'green');


// Will address scaling the below once bars rescale

// x scale
const parser = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z');

const xAxisScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([parser("2022-05-16T14:12:00+00:00"), parser("2022-05-16T20:12:00+00:00")])
  .nice()
  .range([0, svgWidth]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(xAxisScale);

svg.append('g')
  .call(xAxis)
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${svgHeight - 20})`)
  .attr('color', 'red');
```

```html
<div class="viewport"><svg class="svg"></svg></div>
```

```css
 .svg {
/*   margin-left: 30px; */
   width: 100%; /* gets svg to resize */
 }
.viewport {
/*   height: 500px; */
  width: 100%; /* gets container to resize*/
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hiden;
/*   padding-bottom: 100%; */
}
/* .svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  left: 0;
} */
```

Comment: Update: The `<rect>` elements' widths do indeed change when browser width (container width) changes, however the bars are not repainted to be the new width...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm still not sure how to use 'viewbox', but it seems my code `.on('resize', function() {})` code is working. I just had to add the 'transform' attr to my callback function as well.

Cheers.